# Mono switchIfEmpty is always called

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I have a bit more complex use case in Spring Gateway which is based on WebFlux and I ran into small issue with `Mono` usage. Long story short, my `switchIfEmpty` is called even if not required. I prepared small example which allows me to reproduce this problem:

```
public class ReactiveTest {

    @Test
    void test1() {
        isOdd(2)
            .flatMap(this::onNotEmpty)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(this::onEmpty))
            .block();
    }

    Mono<String> isOdd(Integer number) {
        return number % 2 != 0 ? Mono.just("Yes") : Mono.empty();
    }

    Mono<Void> onNotEmpty(String value) {
        System.out.println("Value uppercased " + value.toUpperCase());
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    Mono<Void> onEmpty() {
        System.out.println("Value not present, this shouldn't been called if value was odd");
        return Mono.empty();
    }
}
```

I hope this is pretty self-explanatory, but just to be safe:

- `isOdd(Integer number)` may produce `Mono` with data or empty `Mono`
- I expect `onNotEmpty` to be called only if previous `Mono` had data
- I expect `onEmpty` to be called only if `isOdd` produced empty `Mono`

Unfortunatelly, both `onNotEmpty` and `onEmpty` are called all the time, regardless if I pass odd or even number to `isOdd`.

How can I make sure that `onEmpty` is called only when `isOdd` produced `Mono.empty()`?

Answer (score 2):

The `onNotEmpty(String value)` method is always returning `Mono.empty()`, meaning that `.switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(this::onEmpty))` will always be call either because `isOdd(2)` is already an empty `Mono` or because `onNotEmpty(String value)` method was called and returned an empty `Mono`.

In order to avoid this, you need to change your `onNotEmpty(String value)` method to return something else than an empty `Mono`.

Additionally, please avoid using `block()` since this defeats the whole purpose of using Spring WebFlux by blocking the thread waiting for something to be emitted by the reactive chain.

Comment: `block()` is used only for testing purposes.

Comment: In real world example, this is implementation of `GatewayFilter` which returns `Mono<Void>`. Firstly, I need to check if value is present in DB, this is equivalent of `isOdd` method, then if I have this data, I need to perform some action and return `Mono<Void>` and if I don't have requested data, I just need to call next filter in chain, which also produces `Mono<Void>`. Therefore, I can't really change return type of `onNotEmpty` from this example

Comment: In other words, I'm trying to achieve this `Optional.ofNullable("someValueFromDb").map(this::onNotEmpty).orElseGet(this::onEmpty)`, but instead of `Optional` I have another `Mono` which may be empty

Comment: @lkatiforis
 In real world example, `isOdd` is calling DB in reactive way, therefore it has to return `Mono<String>` that may actually be empty `Mono`

Comment: If you are to perform some action and dont want to return something you should look into the `doOn` operators as these are to be used when dealing with side effects